# Creating a Gmail add-on with AppScript to display warning for external recipients

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace-add-ons

Trying to develop a gmail add-on with AppScript without success

The purpose of my add-on:
After the user clicked on the send button when composing a mail, if the recipient is outside the organization's domain, a warning will be displayed to warn the users to use another platform to send the mail.
The user can cancel this warning/pop-up box, and cancel send the mail.

I learn a lot about the gmail api, but it is not working.

I am adding below the code.

Thank you in advance for your help

```
// Code.gs (Server-side code)

function onGmailMessage(event) {
  var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var recipients = message.getTo();
  var domain = "@domain.com"; // Replace with your organization's domain

  var externalRecipients = recipients.filter(function (recipient) {
    return recipient.indexOf(domain) === -1;
  });

  if (externalRecipients.length > 0) {
    showConfirmationCard();
  } else {
    // No external recipients, proceed with sending the email
    sendEmail(event);
  }
}

function showConfirmationCard() {
  var confirmationCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Confirmation'))
    .addSection(
      CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(
        CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Warning: You are sending an email to external recipients. Are you sure you want to proceed?')
      )
    )
    .addCardAction(
      CardService.newAction().setText('Send').setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('sendEmail'))
    )
    .addCardAction(
      CardService.newAction().setText('Cancel').setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('cancelEmail'))
    )
    .build();

  var response = CardService.newUniversalActionResponseBuilder()
    .displayAddOnCards([confirmationCard])
    .build();

  return response;
}

function sendEmail(event) {
  var messageId = event.gmail.messageId;
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var recipients = message.getTo();
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  var body = message.getBody();

  // Send the email using Gmail service
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);

  // Close the add-on after sending the email
  var response = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setText('Email sent successfully!'))
    .setStateChanged(true)
    .build();
  return response;
}

function cancelEmail() {
  // Close the add-on without sending the email
  var response = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setText('Email canceled.'))
    .setStateChanged(true)
    .build();
  return response;
}
```

Manifest.json/appscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "GMAIL POPUP",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.openlm.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/openlm-svg-logo.svg",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "onGmailMessage"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```